# MySQL VARCHAR storing after setting null

Tags: mysql, memory-management, varchar, database-optimization

I have big MySQL InnoDB table with some varchar(512) column. Next inserted rows depends on previously inserted. After inserting new row, varchar field of previously inserted row will be state meaningless. Previously inserted rows always were marked as 'processed' (by performing update query) but varchar field not erased. This field not indexed. Should I set value of that fields in previously rows to null (by memory saving reasons)?

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR can't be 512! The max for varchar is 255. So for larger amounts of data use TEXT or MEDIUMTEXT.